# How to revert a commit in Git while providing a description?

Tags: git, version-control, configuration-management

I use Git with SourceTree (from Atlassian).

I can revert a commit, but this makes a commit with an auto description : *Revert ...*

I want to revert a commit while entering my own description. How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: If the interface allows you to amend the commit, then amend it and change description. This is not a `git` question but a `SourceTree` question (which I've never used).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for Source tree, but if you have access to the command line and run

```
    git revert YOUR_GIT_OBJECT_TO_REVERT
```

you then will be prompted to change the default message in the defined editor.

Comment: What is `YOUR_GIT_OBJECT_TO_REVERT` ?

Comment: Thanks to you and @twalberg I have succeeded. From SourceTree, I have opened the terminal, and then I have entered the command : **git revert *335e96ef2007...*** But using this terminal is a pain !

Comment: Cool. If your problem is solved, can you mark the question as answered and the answer as accepted?

Comment: My problem is solved, and your answer helped this. But your answer alone did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git revert -e` - that will allow you to edit the commit message and change it from its default "Revert ..." text. Then read `git help revert` for other cool options...